# Improving availability for Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

What's a good strategy to maintain availability with Azure SQL? We've noticing *way* too many service interruptions with messages like

[image]

which basically kill our application entirely. The SLA is *far* from 99.9% and honestly we're not interested in getting a refund, just reliable availability so our customers don't experience app outages. We're actually having better uptimes with a single IaaS VM running SQL than relying on Azure SQL (which totally blows our minds)

Anyway, leaving all those observations behind, programmatically, what is the most economical approach to having better than the advertised 99.99% availability (say an order of magnitude better - 99.999% - 5 mins downtime/year) with Azure SQL? Any specific data access programming pattern(s) and operating procedures anyone recommends?

EDIT: We're already using the Microsoft EntLib 6.0 Transient Fault Handling Application Block library ... 10 retries with 100ms inter-attempt timings. However, it's not 'transient' when these outages are 5+ hours long ...

Comment: All the documentation I have seen says to expect transient failures. Are you using the stuff Microsoft provides to handle those?

Comment: We are using the MSFT EntLib 6.0 Transient Fault Handling Application Block library ... but it aren't "transient" when it's going on for +5 hours ...

Comment: You won't get a programmatic solution to avoiding a 5 hour outage.

Comment: Well, as one example: in an abstract sense I can totally see having master-slave DBs and a round robin selection for the connecting string ... distilling it to programmatic implementation ... help needed. Either case, the objective is to improve on Azure SQLs availability ..

Comment: wow - I'd LOVE to see a guarantee of 5x9s - seriously?  Can anyone provide that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the passive and active geo-replication features of SQL Database -

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/12/spotlight-on-sql-database-active-geo-replication/

Active geo-replication creates additional copies of the database seamlessly in another data centre you can fall back to in case of an issue in a particular data centre

Comment: Except that active geo-replication is about $500/month :( ... something their $150/month plan should already provide considering our $130/month IaaS SQL Server provides better availability ... thanks though.

Comment: What's wrong with standard geo-replication? *Standard geo-replication is an opt-in geo-replication feature that is Microsoft managed. Once a database is opted in a secondary database is created in a pre-paired Azure region within the same geographic area that is at least 500 miles away ... standard geo-replication creates an offline secondary database at the same performance level as the primary database, which is charged at 75% of the primary; for example, if your primary is an S2 and is $75.69 per month, your S2 offline secondary will be $56.77 per month for a total of $132.45 per month.*

Answer (score 0):

We use stovepiped solutions in each datacenter with an external load-balancer/failover solution.  URLs are created to monitor data center faults and failover to another region.

In other words, we built our own business continuity solution to guarantee 5x9s.